# Use reasteasy interface for client proxy and server implementation typesafe

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I can declare an interface for a jax-rs webservice like this:

```
@Path("/foo")
public interface FooRestService {
    class Foo {
        // DTO-Klasse
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/list")
    List<Foo> list();
}
```

I then can use this interface for both the webservice implementation and the client proxy like this:

```
public class FooRestServiceImpl implements FooRestService {
    @Override
    public List<Foo> list() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and on the client...

```
FooRestService service = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build()
    .proxy(FooRestService.class);
List<Foo> foos = service.list();
System.out.println(foos);
```

However, if I want to include http-metadata (status codes, headers etc.) in the response, I have to extract the actual return type in a non-typesafe manner, for example:

```
public class FooRestServiceImpl implements FooRestService {
    @Override
    public Response list() {
        return Response.ok().entity(/* ... */).build();
        // ...
    }
}
```

and on the client...

```
Response response = service.list();
int status = response.getStatus();
final GenericType<List<Foo>> type = new GenericType<List<Foo>>() {};
List<Foo> foos = response.readEntity(type);
```

If I'd use the interface client-side only, I could use a [Response proxy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.5.0.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#Response_proxies) like this:

```
@Path("/foo")
public interface FooRestService {
    @ResponseObject
    interface CustomResponse {
        @Status
        int status();

        @Body
        List<Foo> body();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/list")
    CustomResponse list();
}
```

However, I can't properly use this interface for the server-side implementation, since `ResponseObject` is to be used client-side only with an interface for automatic mapping from generic HTTP-responses, not as a return type on the server side. Is there a way to specify a typesafe return object in the interface, so that it can be used for both the server implementation and the client proxy?

Comment: But you're not using it the same way it is used in the example.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _it_?

Comment: In the link you provided, they do not make the response type an inner class like you are doing. This is the source of your problem right?

Comment: I made it an inner class for simplicity, it has nothing to do with the problem. Imagine it being a separate class

Comment: Oh, never mind, I see what you're saying. The documentation doesn't really give any example of it's usage in the use-case

Comment: It's possible that this feature is not meant to be used server-side. If you read [this](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.5.0.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#Sharing_interfaces), it almost sounds like the focus on the framework was not interoperability with client and server. Them saying that it generally _should_ work, pretty much says that there are some features that will probably not work.